# How can I search by a range of dates in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, erb

I've written a Rails controller function that queries a MySQL database looking for entries that were added within a certain date range. Something like the following, for instance:

```
    @foos = FooTableModel.where(created > ? AND created <= ?', DateTime.new(2011, 1, 26), DateTime.new(2011, 1, 29))
```

This query works great for my purposes. What I would like to do, however, is to allow the user to set their desired date range rather than have it explicitly set. I've poked around with erb files somewhat and I've had great success accessing the data, I'm exclusively interested in altering *what* data I call for to display.

Are there any examples that are similar to what I'm trying to achieve? I assume this is a fairly common thing Rails developers would like to enable their users to do but I haven't had much luck with leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your form code?

Here is a standard REST form:

```
<% form_tag(foo_path) do %>
   <% select_date :start_date %>
   <% select_date :end_date %>
   <%= submit_tag "Submit", :disable_with => "Submitting..." %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller you can use the parameters to search by those dates.

```
start_date = params[:start_date]
end_date = params[:end_date]
```

Keep in mind `foo_path` needs to be restful route. If it is not then you need to pass a hash `{:controller => 'foo', :action => "find"}`

In your controller you can do something like this:

```
def index
   if params[:start_date] && params[:end_date]
       start_date = params[:start_date]
       end_date = params[:end_date]
       @foos = Foo.find(:all, :conditions => ['created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?,' start_date, end_date
   end
   responds_to do |format|
       format.html
   end  
end
```

Comment: This is looking to be very helpful. I've incorporated this code but I'm having a problem on the second line of the view code you provided. It's spitting back out the error: undefined method `day' for :start_date:Symbol

Do I need to add something to the model or controller to make this happier?

Comment: Ah ha, it would seem the following is what I needed there<%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :start_date %>

Comment: Thanks so much, I had one last problem with my script but I figured out I was just accessing the year/month/date info wrong. Thanks so much for your help!